# Me podrían explicar la diferencia de esas tres versiones de mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, informacion

Me podrían explicar la diferencia de esas tres versiones de mysql
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Dicen que la lectura es poder, que libros me podrían recomendar para iniciar en Java y Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Archivos MSI también se denominan archivos de paquetes de Windows Installer, que se utilizan para distribuir actualizaciones de Windows e instaladores de programas de terceros que se han desarrollado para los sistemas basados ​​en Windows.

Archivos EXE proviene de executable (o ejecutable en español) y es una aplicación específica para sistemas basados en Windows.

El primero es un archivo MSI.

Los otros dos son archivos EXE y vienen comprimidos en formato ZIP.

Ahora si quieres saber que contiene cada descarga:

El primero y el segundo es el programa de MySQL (solo que el primero es archivo MSI y el segundo EXE) y el tercero es el programa de MySQL más Debug Binarios y Test Suite.

No se si era lo que esperabas.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias andre a que hace referencia el termino: Debug Binarios y Test Suite.

Comment: Son los conjuntos de pruebas y los componente de información. Mira este link te quedara mas claro: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/windows-choosing-package.html